# What's the difference between type 2 and 2-5 in the COB green bean classification system?

Tags: beans, trade-association

The [Oficial Brazilian Classification (COB)](http://www.coffeeresearch.org/coffee/brazilclass.htm) for green beans defines that if 4 full defects are found in the 300 g sample, the source is classified as type 2, but the table says that it's also type 2-5 (that is, type 2 minus 5 points).

The [norm](https://docplayer.com.br/15106963-Instrucao-normativa-no-8-de-11-de-junho-de-2003.html) specifies intrinsic vs extrinsic defects and explicitly mentions that blacks are primary defects while sours, stinkers and insect damaged are secondary defects, but I don't see where these are taken into account in the pointing system.

What is the distinction between types 2 and 2-5?